# Keep only rows in a range using vim

Tags: vim

I was wondering if there's a way in VIM to keep only rows in a certain range, i.e say I wanted to to keep only rows 1:20 in a file, and discard everything else. Better yet say I wanted to keep lines 1-20 and 40-60 is there a way to do this?

Is there a way to do this without manually deleting stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to keep lines 1 through 20 and 40 through 60, the following construct should do:

```
:v/\%>0l\%<21l\|\%>39l\%<61l/d
```

Answer (score 5):

If you mean entire lines by "rows", just use the `:delete` command with the inverted range:

```
:21,$delete
```

removes all lines except 1-20.

If the ranges are non-consecutive, an alternative is the `:vglobal` command with regular expression atoms that match only in certain lines. For example, to only keep lines 3 and 7:

```
:g!/\%3l\|\%7l/delete
```

There are also atoms for "lines less/larger than", so you can build ranges with them, too.

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this by say asking to keep two ranges i.e keep 1-20 and 40-60?

Comment: Yes, but it's getting more complex; see my edit. It would be good to know your exact use use; your question is just asking about the pure technical solution.

Comment: I've got a alrge text file (100k+rows) thast not very evenly spaced and wish to keep only certain rows for use.

Comment: But how do you get the numbers? Are they fixed, do you read them from another tool's output, or do you get them only by visually inspecting the file in Vim? The best answer depends a lot on that!

Comment: So I open the large master file in vim, and I want to create new files having only rows x to y of the master file.

Comment: That's a totally different use case! So you don't want to modify the original file, but rather save parts of the buffer as separate files?!

Comment: Is there a way to do that? The first way that occured to me was to modify the old file and save that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34696/discussion-between-user1987097-and-ingo-karkat)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to (as I now understand from your comments) save (different) parts of the buffer as new files, it's best to not modify the original file, but to write fragments as separate files. In fact, Vi(m) supports this well, because you can just pass a range to the `:write` command:

```
:1,20w newfile1
:40,60w newfile2
```

Append works, too:

```
:40,60w >> newfile1
```

Comment: And if I wanted both of those to be written in the same file?

Comment: @user1987097 You can use `:40,60w >> newfile1` to append to newfile1

Answer (score 1):

There's not only one way to achieve what you want:

- If this question is really about the first rows in a file:
  `head -20 <filename> > newfile`
- If it shall be a vim solution:
      `:21`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
      `dG`
- However, you [mention](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34696/discussion-between-user1987097-and-ingo-karkat) that you want to split up a large file into smaller pieces. The tool for this is [`split`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split): it lets you split up files into chunks of even line count or even size.

Comment: Should that not be something like `v$Gd` instead of `d$`. `d$` deletes the characters to the end of the line, not until the buffer's end.